# ElidedSemicolonAndRightBrace expected

Tags: java, eclipse, java-stream

I have the following code ("codes" is an array variable):

```
Arrays.asList(codes)
        .stream()
        .filter(code -> code.hasCountries())
        .sorted()
        .toArray()
        );
```

The compiler gives me the following error:

> Syntax error on token ")", ElidedSemicolonAndRightBrace expected

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This error simply means that you have too many closing parenthesis.
The code should be:

```
Arrays.asList(codes)
        .stream()
        .filter(code -> code.hasCountries())
        .sorted()
        .toArray();
```

Comment: You can also improve this by using a method reference `.filter(CodeClass::hasCountries)`.

Comment: ... and by using `Stream.of(codes)` / `Arrays.stream(codes)` instead of `asList(...).stream()..`

Comment: @PaulBoddington With your proposed change, the code would lose its polymorphism and would need to be updated if the type of elements in `codes` changes.